# Как открыть excel из под Питона? Почему завершается процесс?

Tags: python, windows

Доброго дня! Хочу открыть excel из под Питона, но после запуска программа сразу закрывается. Почему и как исправить?

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

def run_app():
    xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    xl.Visible = 1

run_app()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workbooks.Add

```
import win32com.client
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
```